# How to decide on how to define the output function for a neural network?

Tags: machine-learning

What I want my simple ML model to do is for a certain case file, to take the type of crime and the amount of damage(converted into dollars), and to make a judgment (in dollars incorporating price for bailing) based on the two input params given. What I kind of got stuck on is how to define the output function. I understand how the ML system works and all, but I was really confused about what relations/connections I needed to make between the input nodes to create the output function. Could anyone help?

Comment: Please edit the Question and explain your doubt properly.